# Get the client IP in rails when using load balancer and proxy

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, request

I'm using Devise 3.4.1 with Devise's trackable turned on, but the `user.current_sign_in_ip` is wrong because my app is behind a load balancer and proxy, So I want to override the IP address thay Devise uses.

What is the best way to get the client IP address even when using proxy and load balancer?